# Automatically add class-attribute to gallery?

Tags: shortcode, gallery

I'm making a theme for a client in WordPress and he wants each gallery to have a grouped lightbox, so there's a lightbox for each gallery. I found out you can make it add an attribute to the gallery automatically, so what I want is an attribute called `'class'` that has a number that adds by 1 for each gallery created. How would I do that?

**Edit:**
I see that I was not being specific enough so here's some more information:
I want a `'class=""'` attribute added automatically to the shortcode when the post gets created. Inside that class attribute I want it to have a number that goes up by 1 for each post containing a gallery. So the shortcode would end up like this: `[gallery class="1" ...]` and the next `[gallery class="2" ...]` and so on...

Comment: Do you mean native gallery shortcode? Something else?

Comment: Yes sorry. I meant the gallery shortcode.

Comment: @Rarst So, you have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at native galleries they already have IDs with counter implemented:

```
$instance++;
...
$selector = "gallery-{$instance}";
...
$gallery_div = "<div id='$selector'class='gallery...
```

So first gallery within a post will have `<div id="gallery-1"...` and so on. This is used by core itself to target different styles at each instance.

If you need to do something more custom you can use `gallery_style` filter, which gets passed those styles and opening `div` markup, to similarly keep track of instances and inject your custom classes as necessary.

Comment: It's not a class like that. It's a class added to the shortcode, not the div. Sorry for not being specific enough.

Comment: Then you should update your question with more details. Native gallery implementation doesn't allow custom classes.

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: I don't see what the point of adding this to shortcode if this is something native galleries _already do_ (though with IDs, not classes)?

Comment: I'm using a plugin that implements lightbox to the gallery shortcode. He made it so you can seperate them by adding classes like that to the shortcode. I'm pretty new to stackexchange and bad at explaining my problems in text. Sorry.

Comment: No worries. Alas this sounds like a kind of a thing that would require tearing down core gallery function and reimplementing it entirely.

Comment: Can't you just add something to the function that makes the other attributes to the shortcode?

Comment: Look through the source for `gallery_shortcode()`. The filter I mentioned doesn't get access to shortcode arguments, so "just" becomes very involved to implement.